# Set MaterialTimePicker to show 15 minutes intervals

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-timepicker

How can we set [MaterialTimePicker](https://material.io/components/time-pickers/android) to show 15 minutes interval instead of 5 minutes interval?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but that does not seem like it is an available configuration option. There are many other [time pickers](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27?sort=created); perhaps one of them will offer something that you prefer.

Comment: @CommonsWare. Yea, I know there is not any easy way to achieve this, which is quite strange considering its a part of widely know "Material Components". I really liked its interface. :(

Comment: It is open source; you could always fork it. Or, contribute back a change to offer the feature that you are seeking.